# Object into index table

Tags: java

So, I have 3 objects p1,p2,p3.

I'm passing my objects to addItem method from Order class.

I'd like to create an array of `Item[]` and each new object add to next index of that array.

How? In addItem() I have one object with all values of the rest. How to split it?

```java
class Order {
    Item[] items;
    int maxOrderSize;

    public Order(int maxOrderSize) {
        this.maxOrderSize = maxOrderSize;
    }

    void addItem(Item p) {
        System.out.println(p);
    }
}

class Item {
    String name;
    int count;
    double price;

    public Item(String name, int count, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
        this.price = price;
    }

    private double countValueorder(){
        return price*count;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return name +  "    " + price + " EUR     " +   count + "   " + countValueorder()+" EUR";
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       Item p1 = new Item("Test1",3,5.0);
       Item p2 = new Item("Test2",1,0.5);
       Item p3 = new Item("Test3",1,3.5);

       Order z = new Order(20);
       z.addItem(p1);
       z.addItem(p2);
       z.addItem(p3);
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like the code you have will work, if your Order class simulates a List.

Comment: what's the output of that attempt?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following solution for your Order-class:

1. initialize the array `items` with a new Item-Array with the size of the parameter
2. add a new variable to the class `Order` which counts how many Item have been added.
3. use this variable to store the items at the correct place

e.g. the solution could look like this:

```java
class Order {
  Item[] items;
  int itemsInArray = 0;

  public Order(int maxOrderSize) {
    items = new Item[maxOrderSize];
  }

  void addItem(Item p) {
    items[itemsInArray] = p;
    itemsInArray++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are just using an array to store the Items, you have to initialise it in the constructor with a size and then add the items with `Items[0] = p`. If the list is supposed to grow dynamically, try searching for ArrayLists instead.